# Constrain the size of buttons within a linear layout to prevent pushing off screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have a vertical linear layout that is a part of a `scrollView`. In the vertical linear layout I add horizontal linear layouts with 2 buttons in each, one larger button with a name and a small delete button. When the name becomes too big the delete buttons gets squished or essentially removed. I want to avoid this by causing the delete button to always remain the same size and constraining the text button to the space remaining in the layout.
[image]

Here is my save files, I want to prevent the delete button from getting any smaller. This could be either achieved by making the text be on multiple lines, or changing the font size, but none of my attempts have worked as of yet. All the functionality of my program is perfect, but the sizing is making it difficult to have on multiple devices.

Here is the `XML` for the `linearLayout` and `scrollView`:

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/loadScrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/returnToMainButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loadGameText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loadLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

And Here is the code for adding the buttons:

```
    public void addButtons() {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.loadLinearLayout);

        int i = 0;
        for(File file : files) {
            LinearLayout innerLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            innerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            Button newButton = new Button(this);
            String filename = file.getName();

            newButton.setId(i);
            newButton.setText(filename);

            newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    loadGame(view);
                }
            });
            innerLayout.addView(newButton);

            ImageButton deleteButton = new ImageButton(this);
            deleteButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
            deleteButton.setId(500+i);
            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    deleteSave(view);
                }
            });
            innerLayout.addView(deleteButton);

            linearLayout.addView(innerLayout);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the left button of being greedy on the delete button and avoid the delete button to be squeezed, you need a couple of things:

- Add a layout weight to the Button greater than 0.
- Set the width of the horizontal `LinearLayout` to `WRAP_CONTENT`

```
LinearLayout innerLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
innerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

Button newButton = new Button(this);
String filename = file.getName();

newButton.setId(i);
newButton.setText(filename);

newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        loadGame(view);
    }
});

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f); // layout_weight of 1

innerLayout.addView(newButton, params);

ImageButton deleteButton = new ImageButton(this);
deleteButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
deleteButton.setId(500+i);
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        deleteSave(view);
    }
});
innerLayout.addView(deleteButton);


LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // WRAP_CONTENT the widtj
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

linearLayout.addView(innerLayout, layoutParams);
i++;
```

Testing that:

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly for me, thank you so much! I have been struggling with this for too long!